# Gerar títulos de posts automaticamente baseado em campos personalizados

Tags: php, wordpress

tudo bem?
Estou criando um site, unde será cadastrado várias unidades dessa empresa, em várias cidades do Brasil. Eu criei um **post type chamado unidade** e dentre os campos personalizado que criei usando o plugin [advancedcustomfields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) tem um chamado **unidade_estado** onde vai ter um select com todos os estado, para us seus valores eu usei a sigla de cada estado, e criei também um campo personalizado chamado **unidade_cidade** onde vai aparecer um select com todas as cidades de cada estado, com base no estado que a pessoa selecionar acima.

O que eu gostaria era que o título do post fosse gerado automaticamente quando clicasse em publicar, pegando o nome da cidade e o valor do campo personalizado, ficando dessa forma:

```
São Paulo - SP
Cuiabá - MT
Salvador - BA
```

E assim por diante, eu achei um [link](http://www.jennybeaumont.com/auto-create-post-title-acf-data/), mas meu conhecimento em PHP é muito básico, não consegui fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque na postagem o código utilizado

Comment: @VME tu acha que precisa? tanto os custom post type como os campos personalizados eu criei diretamente pela a interface dos plugins